# Как они связанны?

Tags: геометрия

немогу понять как это доказетельство: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

связанно с єтой аксиомой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Псмотрите на рисунок б). Он опирается на утверждение: если два отрезка отложены от начала луча и их длины равны, то и их концы сопадают. Это и сформулировано в аксиоме.

Comment: В аксиоме там написанно: На любой полупрямой от ее начальной точки можно отложить отрезок заданный длины и только один, причем эта аксиома в том доказательстве ??????

Comment: Луч `A1B1`, на нём отложен отрезок длины `|A1,B2|`. Так как `|A1,B2| = |A1,B1|`, то по аксиоме точка `B1` совпадает с `B2`.

Comment: Второй абзац доказательства целиком опирается на эту аксиому.